# How to fix :Error in kmeans$cluster : object of type 'closure' is not subsettable?

Tags: r

I was trying an udemy tutorial for K-Means Clustering, and got the following error while running the code in R:

[image]

What can I do to solve this error?

Comment: This error means that you are trying to treat a function (here, `kmeans()`) as if it was a data frame. Did you run a kmeans analysis prior to this code? If so, what is the name of the object that you stored the results in?

Comment: Yes, I did. But I was using the name "kmeans" as the object name. After changing the name, its working now. Thanks for your help :)